# Installing PHP 5.4 on Samsung Chromebook 3 which runs chroot Ubuntu Crouton

Tags: ubuntu, php5

I am trying to install PHP 5.4 on a Samsung chromebook 3 running crouton.c (Crouton link:  https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton)

I am following the instructions for the upgrade from http://www.barryodonovan.com/index.php/2012/05/22/ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-and-php-5-4-again

But face some dependency issues when I try to install PHP after adding the repository in the above link.

Pasted below is the message I get when I run the `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. I have also removed PHP completely from my system and try to install it after adding the `ondrej/php5` repository but get the same message as the one below.

```
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5 : Depends: libapache2-mod-php5 (>= 5.4.14-1~precise+1) but it is not going to be installed or
                 libapache2-mod-php5filter (>= 5.4.14-1~precise+1) but it is not going to be installed or
                 php5-cgi (>= 5.4.14-1~precise+1) but it is not going to be installed or
                 php5-fpm (>= 5.4.14-1~precise+1) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: php5-common (>= 5.4.14-1~precise+1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I prefer not installing from source. Could some please provide some suggestions to fix this issue or any alternate methods?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget to run:

```
apt-get update
```

and

```
apt-get install -f
```